# MVC dropdown item selected but sometime giving error on validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate if user has selected item in mvc dropdown. And I am checking in jquery but sometimes item is selected but giving validation wrong. 
Here is my code:

**View:**

```
  @Html.DropDownList("RelationType", new List<SelectListItem>()
                           {
                               new SelectListItem() { Text="partnered with", Value="1"},
                               new SelectListItem() { Text ="managed by", Value="2"},
                               new SelectListItem () { Text ="managed", Value="3"},
                               new SelectListItem() { Text ="referred by", Value="4"},
                               new SelectListItem () { Text ="referred", Value="5"}
                           }, "-Select Relation-", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlType" })
```

**Javascript:**

```
 function SaveRelation(relId) {
        var candidateIdd=@candidateId;
        var btnText=$('#btnSaveRelation').text().trim();
        if(!($('#ddlType').val()))
        {
            $.alert("Please select relation type", {
                title: "Relation",
                type: "danger"
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Here is my button click

```
<button id="btnSaveRelation" type="button" class="btn c_B_Btn_L" data-toggle="modal" value="1" onclick="SaveRelation('0')">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Add
                </button>
```

Why sometimes my validation code gets wrong?

Comment: What's the error? What is the rendered HTML? How are you calling `SaveRelation`? Please show a [mcve] which demonstrates the error.

Comment: Here is code to call mentioned function
`<button id="btnSaveRelation" type="button" class="btn c_B_Btn_L" data-toggle="modal" value="1" onclick="SaveRelation('0')">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Add
                </button>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include missing code. Again, please **read** [mcve] and follow its advice.

Comment: Show your validation message , Whats wrong with your message , can you snapshoot ?